# What is the "C:\Windows\-\" (dash) directory?

Tags: windows-7

I found a huge folder `C:\Windows\-\`, which contains a couple of ISO files, one short text file and an exe file, all of which I used a while ago. What is this directory for? Can I remove it?

Comment: **Feel free to delete it since its not a system directory**

Answer (score 1):

It's not a standard Windows folder, and if you recognize what's inside of it, then yeah just go ahead and delete it.

If you're concerned something else might need it, copy it someplace else under a different name for a while first; that way if something complains, you can restore it.